# Code Cleanup: Best way to split long statement over multiple lines

Tags: c#, linq, indentation, code-cleanup

I have a rather long logical statement, and it needs to get split into multiple lines.  Where are the best places to break the statement up?  Is there any convention for splitting up logical operands and linq lambda-expressions?  Visual Studio 2013 with ReSharper formatted a statement this way:

```
var b =
    wmsDocument.Document.Types.All(
        typePair => validTypes.Any(type => type.DocumentTypeId == typePair.DocumentTypeId &&
                                            (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typePair.DocumentSubTypeId) ||
                                                (type.SubTypes != null &&
                                                type.SubTypes.Any(
                                                    subType =>
                                                        subType.DocumentSubTypeId == typePair.DocumentSubTypeId)))));
```

I know I can break up the logic with some method calls, but I really want to know if anyone has conventions on how to indent these kinds of statements.  I haven't had any luck finding anything online so far.

Comment: Ok.  I got some good feedback before this question got put on hold as opinion-based.  Is there a more appropriate location/forum for this question?  If so where?

Comment: your team probably. There is no right or wrong here. There will be a lot of different opinions of what would be "correct" or "more readable". Pick something that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use these rules:

- If the line is too long in lambda expression put definition `x=>` in one line and it's declaration in a new line.
- Break logical operations to align it in a way that shows which operands are related to each other via the operator.

so your code will be something like this

```
var b = wmsDocument.Document.Types.All(typePair =>
    validTypes.Any(type =>
        type.DocumentTypeId == typePair.DocumentTypeId &&
        (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typePair.DocumentSubTypeId) ||
         (type.SubTypes != null &&
          type.SubTypes.Any(subType =>
              subType.DocumentSubTypeId == typePair.DocumentSubTypeId)))));
```

Comment: to add, if you have strings like long sql statements, brake them up like this: "queryqueryquequerquerquer" + "ryqueryquery";

Answer (score 10):

There are various ways to do this. It depends on where you draw the line between compact and readable. This would be on the readable side, and while slightly verbose does allow at least for comments in the nested linq expressions.

```
//determine if every document type
var b = wmsDocument.Document.Types.All
(
    //contains at least one typePair
    typePair => validTypes.Any
    (
        //where the type's id and the typePair's id are equal
        type => type.DocumentTypeId == typePair.DocumentTypeId && 
        (
            //and the subtype's id has a value
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typePair.DocumentSubTypeId) || 
            (
                //or the subtype collection is populated and contains a matching subtypeid
                type.SubTypes != null && type.SubTypes.Any
                (
                    subType => subType.DocumentSubTypeId == typePair.DocumentSubTypeId
                )
            )
        )
     )
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Hard to say there is a good answer to that question. It's really a matter of taste. Personally, I like to break LINQ queries on dots.

```
var result = data
               .Where(a => a == someValue)
               .Take(5)
               .ToList();
```

Also, I prefer to have each condition in a separate line:

```
if (a == b ||
    b == c ||
    c == a)
{

}
```

Applying those two preferences to your query I got something like that:

```
var b =
    wmsDocument.Document.Types
    .All(typePair => validTypes
        .Any(type => type.DocumentTypeId == typePair.DocumentTypeId && 
            (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typePair.DocumentSubTypeId) ||
            (type.SubTypes != null && 
            type.SubTypes
                .Any(subType => subType.DocumentSubTypeId == typePair.DocumentSubTypeId)))));
```